# SQL Query: Select Column1,Count of rows (criteria1),Count of rows(criteria2)

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server, oledb

I need help with a small sql query.
Consider the following table:

```
TicketNo | Rules          | Audit Result
---------------------------------
PR123   | some random strings | Audited
PR123   | some random strings | Not Audited
PR123   | some random strings | Audited
PR123   | some random strings | Audited
PR123   | some random strings | Not Audited
PR123   | some random strings | Not Audited
PR123   | some random strings | Audited
PR999   | some random strings | Audited
PR999   | some random strings | Audited
PR999   | some random strings | Audited
PR999   | some random strings | Audited
PR999   | some random strings | Audited
PR111   | some random strings | Not Audited
PR111   | some random strings | Not Audited
PR111   | some random strings | Not Audited
PR111   | some random strings | Not Audited
```

I need the following result:

```
Ticket | Count of Audited Rules | Count of NOT-Audited Rules
------------------------------------------------------------    
PR123   |   4           |   3   
PR999   |   5       |   0   
PR111   |   0       |   4
```

I tried:

```
Select T1.TicketNo,T1.Audited_Count,T2.NonAudited_Count
FROM
(
    Select [TicketNo], COUNT([TicketNo]) AS Audited_Count
    from [Resolved Results$] where [Audit Result] = 'Audited'
    group  by TicketNo
) T1
inner JOIN
(
    Select [TicketNo], COUNT([TicketNo]) AS NonAudited_Count
    from [Resolved Results$] where [Audit Result] <> 'Audited'
    group  by TicketNo
) T2
on T1.[TicketNo] = T2.[TicketNo]
```

But the above command does not work for those tickets which have oNLY audited rules or ONLY un-audited rules, but works only on the tickets which have both kind of rules.

Can someone please help me out with the query?

PLEASE NOTE: Only inner joins work with OleDB so please avoid using anything other than inner joins.
Thanks a lot

EDIT: Gordon's first answer should ideally work but unfortunately OLEDB driver for Excel does not support it. However, Gordon's suggestion to use the iff(..) worked.

The final Query that I'm using is:

```
select [TicketNo],
       sum(iif([Audit Result] = "AUDITED", 1, 0)) as Audited,
       sum(iif([Audit Result] = "NOT AUDITED", 1, 0)) as NotAudited
from [Resolved Results$]
group by [TicketNo];
```

Thank you Gordon!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want condition summation, which you can do by putting a `case` statement inside a `sum()`:

```
select ticket,
       sum(case when AuditResult = 'Audited' then 1 else 0 end) as Audited,
       sum(case when AuditResult = 'Not Audited' then 1 else 0 end) as NotAudited
from t
group by ticket;
```

This is assuming that AuditResult is a separate column.  If it is the final comment on `SomeStrings`, then the query would look like:

```
select ticket,
       sum(case when SomeStrings like '%Audited' and SomeStrings not like '%Not Audited' then 1
                else 0
           end) as Audited,
       sum(case when SomeStrings like '%Not Audited' then 1
                else 0
           end) as NotAudited
from t
group by ticket;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, but this does not work with OleDB driver, which i am using to connect to an Excel File as datasource.

Error is: 
"Error: IErrorInfo.GetDescription failed with E_FAIL(0x80004005)"

Comment: @Sabz . . . The problem may have been the extra comma (now deleted) on the last column.  If `case` is not supported, then perhaps the Access `iif` is.  The statements would look like `sum(iif(AuditResult = 'Audited', 1, 0))`.

Comment: iff worked.

`select [TicketNo],
       sum(iif([Audit Result] = "AUDITED", 1, 0)) as Audited,
       sum(iif([Audit Result] = "NOT AUDITED", 1, 0)) as NotAudited
from [Resolved Results$]
group by [TicketNo];`

Comment: I'm just testing it with the real-time table. will keep this thread updated

Comment: Heyyy, It works perfectly! :) Thanks AGAIN Gordon :) (You gave me the answer for my last question as well!)

However, How can i sort it by the NotAudited Column? the query doesn't work if i put "order by [NotAudited] desc"

Comment: Sort works if i put 'Select * from (<the above query>) order by notAudited desc' but that is just a hack and not a fix :S\